# What happens with a database table when inserting new records without mentioning a few fields?

Tags: mysql, database

What happens with a database table when inserting new records without mentioning a few fields?

If you have a table with results like this:

```
id, firstname, lastname, comment.
1, Verna, Foulks, Lipsum.
2, Milan, Beaird, Lipsum.
3, Dagny, Plotkin, Lipsum.
```

And then you use a form to add new records to it but you leave for instance the comment section empty or leave it out of the insert statement.

Is the list then going to be like this:

```
4, Marcene, Marone, .
5, Elsa, Maxwell, .
6, Cari, Mccray, .
```

Comment: Did you try that? What is your observation?  What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @purple11111 No I haven't tried it. I rather look for the information or ask the question which undoubtedly will help others as well then to just go try and error it. What I wrote down was what I expected that the field stayed empty. I have seen in the answer below that there could be a default set or otherwise it would be NULL if that is allowed.

Comment: Anyone care to explain why this question gets downvoted. I believe it is a legitimate question. There is no duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try it, you'll find out that anything that you do not provide will be entered as NULL, unless there is another default set.

If any of the columns that have not been provided, are not 'nullable', ie, are allowed to have NULL values, then the insert will fail.

Comment: Thank you for the information that answers the question perfectly.